# Question about hosted VM perfomance; making sense of PerfMon (Win Server 2003)

Tags: windows, hosting

Quick question:

I'm currently shopping around for either a dedicated host or VM host for our 4th Dimension server, and I've set a trial up with one company on a VM machine with the following specs:

> RAID 1 OS, RAID 1 DATA
>
> 2GB RAM
>
> Quad Core Xeon CPU

I have the built-in Windows Performance monitor on it, and when I connect with my remote client to my database, I notice that two of the three lines (Pages/sec for Memory & Avg. Disk Queue Lengh for PhysicalDisk) shoot to the top of the chart and stay at 100 until my query completes, afterwich they both drop back down to nearly 0 and stay there until I run another query.

Is this because I don't have enough memory or because my hard-drive access is too slow? The VM machine is slower at running these queries than our current in-house machine, and I want to make sure it is memory or HD related and not due to network latency... (I know the remote host will be slower than a LAN computer, but I don't think it should be **this** slow...).

Our in-house machine does have 4Gb memory, but is running an older (by several years) AMD single-core processor at an only slightly higher clock speed. Also, since our database server is running on 5 years old, it can only effectively use 2Gb of memory (software cap, I believe).

Any thoughts? (Please pardon the newbie-ness of the question; I'm usually better at coding what's on the systems than the systems themselves.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't spend too much time worrying about PerfMonitor at this point-do you have the capability of running identical queries on both servers and checking their completion time?

However, don't be dismayed by the results you're seeing in PerfMonitor. They don't sound outrageous to me, however the timing results will be better able to illustrate whether the VM is a good fit for you. While you're running the matching queries it may be interesting to open up PerfMonitor and compare the results from both machines as well.